# RESTful API - display returned json in html table

Tags: python, html, flask

I'm trying to do a restful api in flask and python. Here's my code:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request, render_template
from flask_restful import Api, Resource

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

class Tracks(Resource):
    @app.route('/')
    def get(self):
        test = {
            "name": "json2html",
            "description": "Converts JSON to HTML tabular representation"
        }
        return jsonify(test)

api.add_resource(Tracks, '/tracks') 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(port='5002')
```

My question is how should I modify it to be able to display my returned value in table and add e.g. some CSS. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your application return the following:

```
return Response(render_template('test.html', result=test, mimetype='text/html'))
```

and in `test.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <table>
        {% for key, value in result.iteritems() %}

        <tr>
            <th> {{ key }} </th>
            <td> {{ value }} </td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

this was my output: 
[image]

Comment: I did as you said but I receive the html code written in browser